# Put wordpress title inside variable

Tags: php, wordpress

Any idea how to make this work?

`$title =  wp_title();`

The problem is wordpress automatically echoes the `wp_title();`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$title = wp_title('', 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you even looked @ the Wordpress documentation?
Its right here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title

use it like so:

`<?php wp_title( $sep, $echo, $seplocation ); ?>`

where `$echo` is boolean (true/false)

$echo
    (boolean) (optional) Echo the title (True) or return the title for use as a PHP string (False).

```
    Default: True 

    * 1 (True) - default
    * 0 (False)
```